# sharethis icon is not loading

Tags: javascript, html, sharethis

I am using `sharethis` in my website

Everything works properly but there is one problem which i am facing is

1. the icon(ShareThis) which they are providing is not getting loaded when i enter    in to my site. but it is getting loaded after doing refresh

here is my code which i have included

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "45bd003e-483d-41ec-9f43-b7c7bff3e9b1", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
```

this i have included in my main html page

and in current html page

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{{profile.displayName}} Profile"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="{{profile.profileImage}}"/>

<span class="st_sharethis_large"></span><em>SHARE</em>
```

so can someone help me in this

If at all this is not working i would like to change the image(glyphicon-share) but not the functionality

can someone help me on this

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: regarding this there is no data